# Error in creating multiple reports from a R markdown - different names but same data

Tags: r, loops, filter, report, r-markdown

Probably it is a simple problem that I was not able to solve it out yet. I would be glad if someone could help me. 
I am trying to create many reports using R markdown, following these tutorials http://www.nagraj.net/notes/multiple-rmarkdown-reports/ and https://www.r-bloggers.com/many-reports-from-1-rmarkdown-file/. 
Here is my code for the loop:

```
sf$summaries <- sf$summaries %>% filter(ID == i)  
sf_filtered <- sf_filtered %>% filter(ID == i)
for (i in unique(sf$summaries$ID)){ 
rmarkdown::render('/Users/rodri/Desktop/sanger_HC/code/template_animal.Rmd',  # file 2
                  output_file =  paste("report_", i, '_', Sys.Date(), ".html", sep=''), 
                  output_dir = '/Users/rodri/Desktop/sanger_HC/quality_reports')
}
```

My problem is that I tried to filter inside, outside the loop and even in the Rmd template. But in the end, I create multiple reports with different names (as I expected) but all of them containing the data from the same filtering. It looks like I filtered the same data from the first filtering again and again to all the analysis.

So, I suppose I am filtering wrong or I am saving in the wrong object. I do not know. 
This is the code I used to filter, as I said before, I tried to put inside and outside the loop, and also inside the template I am using.

```
sf$summaries <- sf$summaries %>% filter(ID == i)  
sf_filtered <- sf_filtered %>% filter(ID == i)
```

Where is the best place to put the filtering? Should I load the data inside the loop code or in the template.RMD? Should I save the filtered data in a different object with a different name?

Comment: Could you provide a data structure of `sf` or a dummy dataset, for reproducibility. For example `sf$summaries$ID` - this seems like a problem for you loop. I guess what you are after is something like `unique(sf$ID)`, and `sf_filtered <- sf %>% filter(ID = i)` inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The thing is that the function "summarise.abi.folder" creates a list containing one data.frame (which I used by adding $) and a list of S4 objects. So to access the column ID from the data.frame I had to use sf$summaries$ID. 

The problem apparently was that I was altering the primary object called on the loop. So, your comment made me think to create new objects instead of altering the original ones. With that, I was able to create multiple reports. 
`sf_summary <- sf$summaries %>% filter(ID == i)  ` and
  `sf_summary_filtered <- sf_filtered %>% filter(ID == i)`